# How to update while joining the table

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I havie three tables.

Stude_course and its having records like below

```
empid   ename   emp_status  emp_year
1   Raja    6           1
2   Poo     5           2
3   Bhasker 6           3
```

Student1 table contains below records

```
empid   ename   emp_status
1   Raja        6
2   Poo         6
3   Bhasker     6
```

Stud_year contains below records

```
empid   emp_year
1       1
2       1
3       1
```

I need a query to update stude_course.emp_status by using student1.emp_status and to update stude_course.emp_year by using stud_year.emp_year. In order update this records, i used below query

```
update
(
select sc.emp_status stud_emp_status,sc.emp_year stud_emp_year,s.emp_status stud_status,sy.emp_year stud_year from stude_course sc,student1 s,stud_year sy
where sc.empid = s.empid
and s.empid = sy.empid
and sc.empid = 2) st
set st.stud_emp_status = st.stud_status, st.stud_emp_year = st.stud_year;
```

I have joined three tables using equi join and given a alias name as st for the overall joined tables and also given alias name for the columnname and then i tried to update the values with the use of given alias table and column name

Expected result:

```
empid   ename   emp_status  emp_year
1   Raja        6           1
2   Poo         6           1
3   Bhasker     6           1

But i got error like 

SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
           map to a non-key-preserved table.
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.
```

Answer (score 2):

> cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

The columns you are trying to update are in the `STUDE_COURSE` table.  But Oracle, after looking at your table structures, has decided that your join query is not guaranteed to include each row in `STUDE_COURSE` only once.

If you add constraints to your tables that will guarantee to Oracle that rows in `STUDE_COURSE` will not be duplicated in your query, then your `UPDATE` will work.

Let's walk through it.

First, let's recreate your current situation:

#### Setup Tables and Data

```
CREATE TABLE stude_course 
  ( empid number not null,
    ename varchar2(30) not null,
    emp_status number,
    emp_year number );

CREATE TABLE student1 
  ( empid number not null,
    ename varchar2(30) not null,
    emp_status number );

CREATE TABLE stud_year
  ( empid number not null,
    emp_year number );

INSERT INTO stude_course ( empid, ename, emp_status, emp_year)
  VALUES ( 1, 'Raja', 6, 1 );

INSERT INTO stude_course ( empid, ename, emp_status, emp_year)
  VALUES ( 2, 'Poo', 5, 2 );

INSERT INTO stude_course ( empid, ename, emp_status, emp_year)
  VALUES ( 3, 'Bhasker', 6, 3 );  


INSERT INTO student1 ( empid, ename, emp_status)
  VALUES (1, 'Raja', 6);

INSERT INTO student1 ( empid, ename, emp_status)
  VALUES (2, 'Poo', 6);

INSERT INTO student1 ( empid, ename, emp_status)
  VALUES (3, 'Bhasker', 6);

INSERT INTO stud_year ( empid, emp_year)
  VALUES (1, 1);

INSERT INTO stud_year ( empid, emp_year)
  VALUES (2, 1);  

INSERT INTO stud_year ( empid, emp_year)
  VALUES (3, 1);    

COMMIT;
```

## Attempt `UPDATE` (fails)

```
update
(
select sc.emp_status stud_emp_status,
       sc.emp_year stud_emp_year,
       s.emp_status stud_status,
       sy.emp_year stud_year 
from stude_course sc INNER JOIN student1 s ON s.empid=sc.empid
INNER JOIN stud_year sy ON sy.empid=s.empid
where sc.empid = 2) st
set st.stud_emp_status = st.stud_status, st.stud_emp_year = st.stud_year;
```

> ```
> SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table
> 01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
> *Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
>            map to a non-key-preserved table.
> *Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly.
> ```

#### Add constraints to tell Oracle that joins will not duplicate rows from target table

```
alter table stude_course add constraint stud_course_pk PRIMARY KEY ( empid );

alter table student1 add constraint student1_pk PRIMARY KEY ( empid );

alter table stud_year add constraint stud_year_pk PRIMARY KEY ( empid );
```

#### Try it again... (works)

```
update
(
select sc.emp_status stud_emp_status,
       sc.emp_year stud_emp_year,
       s.emp_status stud_status,
       sy.emp_year stud_year 
from stude_course sc INNER JOIN student1 s ON s.empid=sc.empid
INNER JOIN stud_year sy ON sy.empid=s.empid
where sc.empid = 2) st
set st.stud_emp_status = st.stud_status, st.stud_emp_year = st.stud_year;
```

> 1 row updated.

#### Performance Caveat

This kind of syntax isn't common (see other answers posted for alternatives) and I did encounter a weird situation with this once.  What happened is that the CBO optimized the join in a way that the order of rows in the result set was not the same as the order of rows in the table actually being updated.  As a result, Oracle updated blocks all over the place, touching each block multiple times, resulting in really bad performance.  Adding an `ORDER BY target_table.rowid` fixed it.  That was a real head-scratcher.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly update the table as follows:

```
UPDATE STUDE_COURSE SC
SET (SC.EMP_YEAR, SC.EMP_STATUS) = 
(SELECT SY.EMP_YEAR, S1.STATUS FROM STUD_YEAR SY JOIN STUDENT1 S1 
ON (S1.EMPID = SY.EMPID)
WHERE SY.EMPID = SC.EMPID)
WHERE SC.EMPID = 2;
```

or you can also use `MERGE` as follows:

```
MERGE INTO STUDE_COURSE SC
USING
(SELECT SY.EMP_YEAR, S1.EMP_STATUS, S1.EMPID FROM STUD_YEAR SY JOIN STUDENT1 S1 
ON (S1.EMPID = SY.EMPID)) S
ON (SC.EMPID = S.EMPID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE SET SC.EMP_STATUS = S.EMP_STATUS, SC.EMP_YEAR = S.EMP_YEAR
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that the update subquery syntax you are using is feasible when a join is involved.  We can try writing the update using correlated subqueries instead:

```
UPDATE stude_course sc
SET
    emp_status = (SELECT s.emp_status
                  FROM student1 s
                  INNER JOIN stud_year sy ON s.empid = sy.empid
                  WHERE sc.empid = s.empid),
    emp_year = (SELECT sy.emp_year
                FROM student1 s
                INNER JOIN stud_year sy ON s.empid = sy.empid
                WHERE sc.empid = s.empid)
WHERE
    sc.empid = 2;
```

Comment: This can also be written with a single sub-query. `(emp_status, emp_year) = (select s.emp_status, sy.emp_yer from ...)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Great trick...I'll try to remember that!